# Clickable Image link in Wordpress Widget

Tags: wordpress, e-commerce

How do I add a clickable image link in a Wordpress Sidebar Widget.

I am doing a graphic with "social media link" and want to make this a clickable link.

I have created the graphic, no idea where to start with the clickable link.

Answer (score 3):

First, you will want to upload the selected image to the media gallery of your WordPress site.
Second, Copy the "Copy Link" from the details window of your image.

[Copy Link Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcimf.jpg)

Once you have the link copied, hover over the "Appearance" tab of the left menu. While hovering over appearance, new options will show up...one will be "Widgets". Select that.

[Widget Location in Menu Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHZ8Z.jpg)

On the widget screen there will be a list of all the types of widgets to add, select "Custom HTML" and add that to your desired widget location (sidebar). For the content of your HTML widget use this code:

```
<a href="www.YourTargetURL.com">
<img alt="test" src="www.YourCopyLink.com" height="250px" width="250px"/>
</a>
```

[Custom HTML Widget Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lv6uo.jpg)

You will need to replace the placeholder URLs in the code example above with your target site URL and the link you copied from the image details page. Click "Save", and make adjustments to the size as needed.

Hope that helped!

-Spencer